# Slow Scapy start up

Tags: scapy

Lately I installed Scapy for python 2.7, and every time I try to start it (Whether through `python27/Scripts` and whether using `from scapy.all import *`) it takes about 30 seconds or so to start up. I installed the latest dnet, winpcap, pyreadline and pypcap. Does anyone have any idea why it happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As of 2.4.3rc+, Scapy boot time on Windows has been drastically reduced (now using C calls to query Windows): try it out using `pip install --pre scapy`**

Late answer,

First, you can get the latest Scapy  version of the GitHub repo, which do not require any other packages than pyreadline. That might improve the loading speed.

Scapy on windows take way more time to load because of the powershell calls that are slow.

Comment: I saw tutorials on YouTube and it took there way less time than on my computer. I'm pretty sure it has to do with the modules import. Is there any way to improve that?

Comment: Updated as of today